# kibana, elasticsearch 7.2 local setup (No living connections)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Elasticsearch: 7.2
Kibana: 7.2

My docker compose file:

```
app-elasticsearch:
  build: ./docker-elasticsearch
  container_name: elasticsearch
  expose:
  - "9200"
  - "9300"
  ports:
  - "9200:9200"
  - "9300:9300"

app-kibana:
  build: ./docker-kibana
  container_name: kibana
  links:
    - app-elasticsearch
  environment:
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://app-elasticsearch:9200"
  volumes:
    - ./docker-kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
  expose:
  - "5601"
  ports:
  - "5601:5601"
```

Elasticsearch dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
RUN echo discovery.type: single-node >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Kibana dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.2.0
```

Kibana config file:

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

And it seems the elasticsearch is working properly as I check localhost:9200:

```
curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "d71d595bd9e6",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xTdg1O_LRLiiNyO1265XLA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.2.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "508c38a",
    "build_date" : "2019-06-20T15:54:18.811730Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But the kibana log is the following:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:02Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:02Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana               | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-22T02:55:05Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":1,"message":"PollError No Living connections"}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue or any configuration for setup elasticsearch & kibana 7.2 are welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was totally my mistake. I run the kibana on docker container so the `elasticsearch.hosts` should be ["http://app-elasticsearch:9200"]. I set it on docker-compose file but also redefined it in the config file wrongly.

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://app-elasticsearch:9200"]
```

This works for me.

Comment: yes! yo should use the elastic search service name